# Has anyone programmed ATmega8A using USBasp?

Tags: atmega, usbasp

I have failed to program ATmega8A using USBasp. I am sure that the wiring is ok. I have programmed an ATtiny13A several times with the same USBasp. However, no luck with the ATmega8A. This is the error avrdude shows-

```
avrdude.exe: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1    
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check.
```

I tested without the microcontroller connected and found the same error. Which means I have broken connection. I don’t think so.

Is there any possible reason avrdude shows this error without broken connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup might just be flawed.

I have programmed not specifically the ATmega8, but I have done an ATmega16 which is the same process.  [I note the article on my website](http://shannonstrutz.com/?p=629) which has been used by many.

At one point in the article I list a command:

```
-c usbasp -p atmega16 -B12 -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i
```

You will change this to

```
-c usbasp -p atmega8 -B12 -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i
```